# Differential Geometry-curves

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $c:[0,2] \to\Bbb R^3$ be the  curve given by $$c(t)=(\frac {t^3}{3},t^2,2t).$$

Then there exists an $m>0$ and a $C^{\infty}$ bijection $f:[0,m]\to [0,2]$ such that $f'(s)> 0$ for every $s\in[0,m]$ and  such that the curve $b:[0,m]\to \Bbb R^3$ given by $$b(s)=c(f(s))\qquad (*)$$ satisfies  $|b'(s)|=1$ for every $s\in[0,m]$.
The question is to find $m$.

A thought of mine is this one:

Let $f(t)=\int_{0}^{t} |c'(t)|dt$ for $t\in[0,m]$. Then $f'(t)>0$ and has all the required properties.

Thus $f(m)=2$ adn we have that $\int_{0}^{m} |c'(t)|dt=2\int_{0}^{m} \sqrt{t^4+t^2+1} dt=2$ or $\int_{0}^{m} \sqrt{t^4+t^2+1} dt=1$. From here i should find $m$. But the indefinite integral of this root function cannot be found and the definite integral of this it should be hard, and i also don't know how to find it either.

Any help? Can you find another way of solving the problem?

Thanks

Comment: I didn't understand how you got $|b'(s)| = 1$ by choosing $f$ as you did? Please explain

Comment: Although it is almost hidden with all the symbols in this problem, note that the $m$ you're looking for must be the arclength of your curve $c(t)$, $0\le t\le 2$. So $m=\int_0^2 |c'(t)|dt$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a small error making the integral impossible.

Go back to calculating $c'$:

$$
c'(t) = (t^2,2t,2)
$$

so

$$
|c'(t)| = \sqrt{t^4 + 4t^2 + 4} = \sqrt{(t^2 + 2)^2}
$$